# Merge comments from Facebook with WP comments

Tags: comments, plugin-recommendation, facebook, comment-form, social-sharing

I'm looking for a way to integrate Facebook comments (actual comments **from** facebook) into the comment section of a wordpress post?

So what I need is; when someone comments on an URL-post on facebook about for example page.com/post, it shows up on page.com/post as well, merged with comments posted on the page itself.

Is this possible? Is there any plugin I can use for this?

Comment: Sorry, but this is way too broad, and also, asking for plugin recommendations are off topic here. Please see [ask] and [help]

Comment: @PieterGoosen Really feels like this stack is not helpful at all! Because you are -1 everything and comment bad and negative, let's just help eachother! Like stackoverflow for example. Below is a very helpful answer.

Comment: It is dangerous to make assumptions without prove :-). Also, I was not in any way rude in my comment. The site has policies to which I just alerted you to and which you should read and take note of. If you have a problem with the way I addressed you, you are free to flag my comment for moderator attention. :-) Thank you

Comment: For moderatition? Why? No thats net necessary at all. But I haven't made an assumptions, I just give my opinion. And you are not very helpful.

Comment: I'm really sorry you do feel that way and sorry if I came across as rude and not friendly. I'm not here to fight, nor do I want to start one :-). We all need to however stick to site policy and we need to stick to what is on and off topic here. Also, you have recieved an answer, it is now your responsibility to give feedback to the user who left the answer. Simply keeping quite is also not useful. Check in [help] what you should do if someone answers your question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are a number of plugins that can accomplish this:

- http://peadig.com/wordpress-plugins/facebook-comments/
- http://aaroncollegeman.com/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/

Naturally, I can't really vouch for these plugins working *well*, but that is the case with any plugin. Make sure to take backups first and good luck!